# How to call a JS by other JS in Aura Component

Tags: javascript, aura

I have two components, **Spinner** and **SaveAccount**.

The component Spinner is to show loading, and the component SaveAccount is to save account but **while don't save, must show loading.**

I need to use **SpinnerController.js** in **SaveAccount.js**. HOW TO?

**SaveAccountController.js**

```
save : function(component, name){
    const sc = new SpinnerController();

    //dont works
    sc.showLoading();

    const action = component.get('c.saveAccount');
        
    action.setParams({ 
        name: name
    });

    acao.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        //dont works
        sc.hideLoading();
    });
        
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**SpinnerController.js**

```
showLoading : function(component, name){
    component.set("v.loading", true);
},

hideLoading : function(component, name){
    component.set("v.loading", false);
}
```

How do I make this??? please!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aura, you have expose methods via [`aura:method`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm), then call them using an instance of the component. You can't just create a new class like that and have it work.

```
<!-- saveAccount.cmp -->
<c:spinner aura:id="spinner" />
```

---

```
// saveAccountController.js
someFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.find("spinner").showLoading();
  // or
  component.find("spinner").hideLoading();
}
```

---

```
<!-- spinner.cmp -->
<aura:method name="showLoading" />
<aura:method name="hideLoading" />
```

---

```
// spinnerController.js
showLoading: function(component) {
  component.set("v.loading", true);
}
hideLoading: function(component) {
  component.set("v.loading", false);
}
```

---

Please read the documentation for more information.

---

That said, it's probably easier to just expose the attribute.

```
<!-- saveAccount.cmp -->
<aura:attribute name="loading" type="Boolean" default="{!false}" />
<c:spinner loading="{!v.loading}" />
```

...

```
// saveAccountController.js
someFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.loading", true);
  // or
  component.set("v.loading", false);
}
```

This is the preferred method of communicating with a child component whenever possible.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!